# Swift/JS Restore WebView Back Forward List

Tags: swift, webkit, wkwebview

I am trying to figure out how to restore the back forward list in a WKWebView. Apple defaults the BackForwardList to be readonly. However, FireFox, Chrome, and other mobile browsers are able to restore it each session.

This is how FireFox restores it on iOS: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/wiki/History-Restoration-in-WKWebView-(and-Error-Pages)

Here is the JS/HTML code that's used to access the DOM History API: https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/041c85483b1aa4a4e357d8bd9419550e4f20347a/Client/Assets/SessionRestore.html

In order to load this file and restore a WKWebView's history, do you need to spin up a local server within the app?

It seems like you would need to in order to access a `local://` url that points to this JS file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, that's what they are doing, according to [WebServer.swift](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/c74a89eb5ad9886176588111def48f639ec88fed/Client/Application/WebServer.swift). There are many references in the code to `internal://`, and an `InternalURL` struct in [URLExtensions.swift](https://github.com/mozilla-mobile/firefox-ios/blob/c74a89eb5ad9886176588111def48f639ec88fed/Shared/Extensions/URLExtensions.swift). There are session restoration things in that file as well, such as `var isSessionRestore: Bool`.

If you haven't already, clone the project and open it in Xcode for easier navigation and searching.